# How to Copy a Data Row from my Student Table to another table (Student Record)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a login system using java and I have last problem to my system.

When I type and login the Student ID Number of a Student in JTextField only, it will display his or her first and last name in a text field.
[Here is my Student Login System.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH53q.jpg)

my problem is,
when I login his or her student id, I want to copy the data of a student like the student id, first name, middle name, last name and insert into my Student Record table in PMA.
here is my code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdatabase","root","");

                String student_id = txtStudent_ID.getText();
                String sql = "INSERT INTO 'studentrecord' (stud_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name) "
                        + "SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname FROM 'student' WHERE student_id = '" + student_id + "' ";

                if (student_id.length() > 0) {
                    Statement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                    if (student_id.length() > 0) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                    String firstname = rs.getString(3);
                    String lastname = rs.getString(5);

                    txtFirstName.setText(firstname);
                    txtLastName.setText(lastname);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in", "Success",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry!, No data found for this ID", "Student ID",
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a Valid ID", "Student ID Information",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                        txtStudent_ID.setText("");

            }
                }
                }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQL Syntax should be reviewed", "Database",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


        }
```

it will have an error and it says that "SQL Syntax should be Reviewed"
Need help.

Comment: Perhaps java interprets `'` differently, but normally in MySQL, `'` indicates a string literal. For table/column identifiers, we would normally use `\``, or omit altogether.

Comment: Also, it's obviously nonsensical to include in the `SELECT` a different set of columns from those mentioned in the `INSERT`

Comment: how to code that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know java, so instead, here's an example of a valid MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO studentrecord 
(first_name, middle_name, last_name)
SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname 
  FROM student WHERE student_id = 'student_id'
```

or

```
INSERT INTO studentrecord 
(stud_id,first_name, middle_name, last_name)
SELECT stud_id,firstname, middlename, lastname 
  FROM student WHERE student_id = 'student_id'
```

(The fact that `stud_id` and `student_id` are different is something only you can know how to resolve!)

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping `'` as below

```
"INSERT INTO \'studentrecord\' (stud_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name) "
            + "SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname FROM \'student\' WHERE student_id = \'"+ student_id + "\' ";
```